# What is the difference between minimal and full chroot?

Tags: linux, chroot, desktop-environment

While installing a linux distro I found many types of tar.gz files. But I found that, about every distro (For Different architecture) has two files indicated with minimal.tar.gz and full.tar.gz
I have installed a minimal one because I don't have that much memory drive. What is the main difference between minimal and full chroot?
Can a minimal chroot be turned into a full chroot by installing different packages?

Comment: Depends on the distro. Please advise which distro by clicking [edit] and adding that info to your question. Please do not answer via Add Comment as new comments push off comments offscreen.

Comment: I think you are not telling us something: the word `chroot` seems to just hand there. Not attached to any other concept, that you are discussing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one example which may or may not fit: [Nethunter](https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-nethunter/wiki/Nethunter-Components) relies on Kali Linux and has a minimal chroot, which is a little over 100 MB in size; it is a bare bones basic Kali OS with nothing installed and is great for developers or anyone looking to customize their installation.

The full chroot is what most users will want to download and comes in around 600 MB. The full chroot has everything needed to integrate with the Android application.

You can expand the minimal chroot by selectively adding packages until you have the capabilities of the full chroot.

Comment: This is the answer I was seeking for 2 months. Thank you. I tried to find it on google but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Google search on "full chroot" is how I found it.